# Why my programs throws error when trying to load a custom ListView on SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

i'm new on android development and i was trying to create a slide menu using values from an string array. I want to do it like this way because i want to customize each row with the appropriate icon and then the text of the slide menu to multi language. When i load the code it shows that is reading all the values but then it throw an exception here is my code: (my code is based on this example [Tutorial: ListView in Android using custom ListAdapter and Cache View](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/))

my code:

```
public class Slide_Menu extends SherlockListFragment {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();;
    private ListView listView;
    private Context ctx;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG,"Slide Menu is called");
        this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_menu, null);
        this.ctx = getActivity();
        return this.view;

    }

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"Slide Menu is on onActivityCreated");
        try {
            List menu_list= new ArrayList();
            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] menu_values = res.getStringArray(R.array.slide_menu_options);
            for(int i=0; i<=menu_values.length;i++)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"Adding the items on the Slide Menu: " + menu_values[i].toString());
                menu_list.add(new SlideMenu_Contents(menu_values[i].toString(),"search"));
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Slide Menu is on Loop");
            this.listView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.list);
            this.listView.setAdapter( new SlideMenu_Adapter(this.ctx, R.layout.single_row_slidingmenu, menu_list ) );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Error on loading the string menu on Slide Menu.");
        }
      }
}
```

The other files like SlideMenu_Adapter,SlideMenu_Contents are the same with the examples, i changed them base my needs, like the SlideMenu_Contents has only a text and image.

Here are my layouts:
**single_row_slidingmenu.xml**

```
    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_option"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:contentDescription=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slidemenu_text_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**slide_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/slidemenu_list_selector">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:divider="#1e1e1e"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/slidemenu_textcolour"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/slidemenu_list_selector">

    </ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Programming questions should be asked in StackOverflow.com :)

Comment: a ok sorry about that!!!

Comment: No worries. The mods will probably move this question to SO some time later.